# Solution for alternative PNG depending on screen-size

Tags: html

What would be a solid solution if a have an  file to show a ad-banner in wordpress (for example: https://www.lapetitebox.ch/lifestylegossip/aveda-love-your-color-haarfarben-zum-verlieben/ - see the "la petite box" banner after the author) to switch the image on mobile devices?

Because actual the image doesn't make sense on mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with JS is guess. Something Like

```
 if (screen.width <= 699) {

        }
```

should be a first step. Or maybe there is a nice plugin you could search for. Maybe you find something with the Keywords "change banner on smartphone" 
Greetings from germany.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it would be to use the css @media rule:

```
@media only screen and (max-height:650px)
{
    .lapetitebox
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Experiment with height or width as you please (give the image a classname of 'lapetitebox')